# PHP Make a multidimensional array from object properties

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a really tough situation in here.

There is an array of these objects

```
ProductionItem Object
(
    [customer] => Customer Object
        (
            [customer_id] =>24
            [company_type] => Limited Company
            [date_created] => 2009-01-28 15:55:50
            [vat] => 
            [status] => 1
            [account_number] => 590893
        )

    [woi_id] => 67017
    [od_id] => 7154
    [pd_id] => 1112
    [od_qty] => 0
    [od_color] => TEAL BLUE
)
```

I am trying to convert it to a multidimensional array of something similar to this structure

```
$allOrders[24] = array (
        objects[0] => array(
                'woid_ud' = 67017,
                'od_id' = 7154,
                'pd_id' = 1112,
                'od_qty' = 0,
                'od_color' = 'TEAL BLUE'
                ),
        objects[1] => array(
                'woid_ud' = 75839,
                'od_id' = 5890,
                'pd_id' = 2344,
                'od_qty' = 0,
                'od_color' = 'TEAL GRAY'
                )
        )
```

Is there anything I am missing and this is really easy to do? Please, advice me. I tried iterating through those object and it still does not work and looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php).

```
function object_to_array($obj){
    if(!is_object($obj)){
       return $obj;
    }
    $data = array();
    foreach(get_object_vars($obj) as $k=>$v){
        $data[$k] = object_to_array($v);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But the problem I have is slightly different. I need ProductionItem->customer->customer_id to become the index of the array and  [woi_id] => 67017
    [od_id] => 7154
    [pd_id] => 1112
    [od_qty] => 0
    [od_color] => TEAL BLUE to be accessible via array[0][43]['od_id']. Then, as it as an array of objects, via array[1][99]['od_id'], where 99 is customer_id

Comment: Thank you for response. I figured out how to do the task in a different and more elegant way without a multidimensional array.